# Oracle procedures vs MS procedures vs Oracle packages

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, package

I was told by someone that when you create procedures in Oracle you should create a Package with procedures in it.  Is this a true statement?  Are procedures in MS the same as Oracle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have to put your procedures and functions inside a package, but it is generally considered a best practice. Bundle them by function and they are a lot easier to organize.

One exception to this is the [AUTHID clause](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/subprograms.htm#i18574). That can only be specified for an entire package or a standalone procedure/function. Different procedures inside a single package cannot have different privileges.

Answer (score 3):

Procedures in Oracle and MS are similar, but yes, in Oracle, you make a package declaring the procedure, then you define the procedure in the package body

[This](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0540__Function-Procedure-Packages/Packages.htm) has some good info on how to build an Oracle package

Comment: Thanks I had someone recently tell me that I could did not have to create packages... I kept having trouble.  I got one to work.

Comment: You can [create a procedure](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_6009.htm#i2072424) (or [function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5009.htm#i2153260)) outside a package, but unless you're doing something that's going to be used across the database it's generally preferable to use packages, and often easier - you don't have to worry about clashing names, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Stored procedures and functions are very similar between Oracle and SQL Server (or MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc).  A SQL function is intended to always return a SQL data type; a stored procedure can return a SQL data type but doesn't by default.

An Oracle package is an awesome tool.

- SQL Server has assemblies, but they aren't as immediately accessible as Oracle packages.
- Besides being a container for functions and stored procedures, Oracle packages support variable declaration when other alternatives would only expose via functions.
- Oracle packages also allow for logical grouping of functionality, without needing to setup schemas (for namespacing).  Because of what's contained in a package, you deploy the package -- not the functions/stored procedures individually.
- My only regret was that IME (Oracle 9i, 10g), you could not drill into the specific function/stored procedure/line when tracing references.

There's nothing requiring you to use Oracle Packages, but you really stand to benefit by using them vs not.  I don't understand why other vendors haven't reproduced the functionality in their own way.

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of reasons to use packages over standalone procedures/functions, and a few situations when you wouldn't use packages.  Instead of trying to rehash them from memory, I'll point you to an excellent article from pl/sql guru [Steve Feuerstein](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2005/05-may/o35plsql-085074.html).

Note: The article is several years old, but the rationale still holds imo